Valid Variant ㅌ Stroke Order?
So apparently I've been doing ㅌ wrong but I do find some materials that show the way I do it, which is basically ㄷ but with the middle line added last.
https://i.etsystatic.com/8897793/r/il/3f3098/3962565324/il_1080xN.3962565324_kosr.jpg

But this is apparently the right way?

https://www.90daykorean.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/12-min-1536x441.png
Does anybody have any input?

https://korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=294929

There is no "right" way to write any language's characters.  I would ignore both the suggested methods in your question and use your own intelligence.

@Chenmunka, I appreciate your contribution, but doesn't stroke order actually impact readability (especially when the text was written quickly) when it comes to Korean?

Not in my experience.  You mention speed, that can always affect legibility, irrespective of stroke order.

Stroke order is more important in Chinese, as it affects the collation order of characters in dictionaries. Also, there are a lot of Chinese characters that could be confused for each other when badly written, and seeing the order the strokes were made in can help decide what character was intended. Korean has only a small alphabet, so there is little chance of confusion.

Sometimes ㅌ is written with the ㄴ stroke starting at the middle ㅡ stroke, leaving a gap between the top and middle ㅡ strokes, creating an appearance like 云 (minus the last dot), or like ㄷ with a ㅡ over it.
Those forms of ㅌ suggest a ㅡㅡㄴ stroke order rather than ㅡㄴㅡ.
example:
Professor Yoon has a video on reading Korean store signs and the Starbucks Coffee (스타벅스 커피) features this kind of ㅌ (also notable is how ㅂ and ㅍ are written).
On the other hand, I looked through all the Korean fonts on Google fonts and only found one font (Dyphylleia) with such a ㅌ. Whereas, there are some fonts with the middle ㅡ not connected to the rest of the letter such as Hi Melody and Single Day, which suggests to me a ㅡㄴㅡ stroke order.
My very ad-hoc reasoning is that if up-left diagonal movements of the pen are shortened in general (which would be consistent with the 云-like ㅌ), then in the ㅡㄴㅡ order, the final ㅡ stroke would not meet the ㄷ. Though, another ad-hoc principle could be that later strokes have more precise starts because they have previous strokes for reference, so conversely, a ㅡㅡㄴ stroke-order would result in the middle ㅡ stroke starting too far right, and then the ㄴ starts accurately on the top ㅡ but misses the middle ㅡ (or crosses it like in Nanum Pen Script).
Anyways, maybe there's some actual research on the effect of stroke order on spelling. And of course you could just ask Reddit and I think native speakers will tell you they use either one but the ㅡㅡㄴ is correct. I found this Reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/comments/144nzcc/different_ways_of_writing_%E3%85%8Ctieut/ which says ㅌ is originally ㄷ with a line over it, so in older texts or in North Korea, the top stroke can be vertical.
